# System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, compact-framework, pocketpc

I am working on compactframework c# vs 2005.
My PDA device is Pocket pC 2003 device.

I installed my application and running successfully in my PDA device.when i released the project to client and when he deployed and start running the application, he is getting an error

"System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
at System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes()".

Stack Trace is here

```
Exception: System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
at System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes()
at  BinaryEncoder.EncodeVariableString()
at DataHolder.encodeValue()
at  UpdateInformation.encode()
at DataHolder.encodeValue()
at LogonRequest.encode()
at MessageFactory.getRequestMsg()
at MessageFactory.getRequestMsg()
at LogonManager.logon()
at doLogon()
at frmLogin.btnNext_Click()
```

> public static int EncodeVariableString( string str, byte[] rawData,
>   int encodePos ) {             int curPos = encodePos;
>                 int len = str.Length.ToString().Length;             curPos = EncodePositiveInt32(len, rawData, curPos, 1);
>
> ```
>                   curPos = EncodePositiveInt32(str.Length, rawData, curPos, len);
>
>         return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str, 0, str.Length, rawData, curPos) + curPos;         }
> ```

Client is also entering the same username and password, but he is getting error and i am not getting error. It should throw error in both PDAs right.
I have hard coded the values given by the client. It is working in my PDA,but it is not working in client PDA.
One difference i have seen is , in my PDA Byte[] rawdata.length=105
and in client PDA it is rawdata.length=96.

I am unable to reproduce the error in my device.

Any thoughts  on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: where are you calling that function?

Comment: He can enter non-ASCII chars and you can't?

Comment: Which of these overloads is your code using? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.getbytes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A stack trace would be nice. The calling code would be nice. Which overload of `GetBytes`? Can you figure out the data being passed to `GetBytes`?

Per the documentation, there are three overloads of `GetBytes` that throw an `ArgumentException`:

[`GetBytes(Char*, Int32, Byte*, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5hc2tkh.aspx)

[`GetBytes(Char[], Int32, Int32, Byte[], Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149283.aspx)

[`GetBytes(String, Int32, Int32, Byte[], Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/595a8te7.aspx)

Basically, the error indicates that you didn't give `GetBytes` enough space to store the resulting bytes.

Look at your calling code, are you remembering to allocate enough space for the array?

Comment: the same code is running successfully in my PDA. and it is not running on the client PDA.he is also entering the same values for login

Comment: Is the client PDA localized for English, or for some other language?

Comment: Also, show your code - you're probably doing something somewhere where you assume 2 bytes per character in the original string.